# My discord bot isn't responding to commands. C#

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have been losing my mind over this for three days. I have been making a discord bot, when eventually i just copied the code from this [Github](https://github.com/Rikkaede/TutorialBot), but i have been running into a problem which prevents me from using the commands i have coded. I thought at first that it would be about these two warnings/errors:

```
17:05:44 Gateway     You're using the GuildScheduledEvents gateway intent without listening to any events 
related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
17:05:44 Gateway     You're using the GuildInvites gateway intent without listening to any events related 
to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
```

I don't know yet how to fix those but i tried to Console.WriteLine the part where it recognises the code, but nothing comes up. Here's the two scripts i use:

Main.cs :

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TutorialBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;

        
        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();

            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            string token = "NjQ0NTI3NzE3Mjk0OTMxOTg4.GeEFaJ.C36VPhtg0MRVRzRinneTIjoJAQrZfdHFBjJdQs";

            _client.Log += _client_Log;

            await RegisterCommandsAsync();

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);

            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);


            var config = new DiscordSocketConfig{
                //GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.GuildInvites 
                GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.GuildScheduledEvents
                
                
                
            };
            var client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
        }
        

        private Task _client_Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command recognised");
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            int argPos = 0;
            if (message.HasStringPrefix("K!", ref argPos))
            {
                
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
                if (!result.IsSuccess) Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
                if (result.Error.Equals(CommandError.UnmetPrecondition)) await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`
Modules.cs :    (This script contains the output for the commands)

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace TutorialBot.Modules
{
    public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("ping")]
        public async Task Ping()
        {
            await ReplyAsync("pong");
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please reset your bot token **immediately**, as you just posted it to the internet for all to see and steal. Consider reading secrets from configuration, not hard coded in your source code.

Comment: The GitHub you posted in 3 years old (out of date)...you should probably look at the tutorials and the sample projects [provided](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/tree/dev/samples) by the lib

Answer (score 0):

into RunBot Async() change client property to this

```
    var configuracoes = new DiscordSocketConfig()
    {
        GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All
    };
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient(configuracoes);
```